# Need to flash the screen GREEN for 5 secs

Tags: android

I have a particular requirement.

```
if(condition true){
    Flash the screen GREEN for 5 secs
}else{
    Flash the screen RED for 5 secs
}
```

Could anyone please help in this regard?

Comment: what does flash mean? like blinking green for 5 seconds or just display total green screen for 5 seconds?

Comment: yes i meant blinking green for 5 secs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. start a new activity
2. in these activities set the content views to a different XML files
3. in the layouts of the XML files...set this :

`Android:background="#ffff0000"` for red
and `"#ff00ff00"` for green

1. and destroy it after 5 sec

Comment: If you want to animate it using a single view, you can just find the View by it's ID, and set it's color programmatically. Use the .findViewById(..) method to get the View.

Comment: That might give an error occasionally. i.e. If the XML file is defined and U have changed it midway... the Buttons and Other views defined in the parent XML will throw a force close... Hence the new activity

Comment: Avishek, sorry for my ignorance but could you please elborate a bit on the comments!

Comment: i need it to blink green for 5 secs